# syntax error, unexpected token "::" when calling "all()" or "get()" in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm working on an application that stores information about Esports matches using Laravel 8 and a MySQL server. When generating a simple index page for each of the models by using the "all()" function, they all work perfectly fine except for my "Matches" model. I get the following error message:

`syntax error, unexpected token "::", expecting "("`

It specifically highlights the first line in the body of the following "index" function in the Matches controller...

```
public function index()
{
    $matches = Match::get();
    return view('matches.index')->with('matches', $matches);
}
```

In a slightly strange twist, I only receive this error when the application is deployed to a Heroku server. A local Laravel server does NOT produce this error, everything works perfect!

Maybe Laravel is trying to use an older Model or Controller file?

Let me know if there is anything else I need to share.

Thanks!

Comment: let me guess... you're using php 8

Comment: Nope, just plain old 7.4.3 :)

Comment: please share matches.index code

Comment: Do you have a function called `match` in that same controller?

Comment: @CBURG Can you verify this by a `phpinfo()` call or something in the `index.php` file?
The error you get is a php 8 error, as `match` is a keyword there. Have a look at this: https://3v4l.org/DKedv

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for the replies guys! I will try and change the model/controller to something like "Matchup" and see if that fixes it!

Comment: @CBURG Could you please share information `local` server and `Heroku` server?

Answer (score 4):

I've now solved the issue. I did not know Heroku uses PHP 8 (so that was the first rookie mistake!). Secondly, I had created a model with the same name as a keyword from PHP 8 - hence why this problem didn't occur on my local machine running PHP 7.

Answer (score 2):

Match is a reserved word in PHP 8 - I had the exact same problem, call your model something like Result instead and remember to rename the file and class name.

```
public function index()
{
  $matches = Result::get(); // Change from 'Match' which is a reserved word in PHP8
  return view('matches.index')->with('matches', $matches);
}
```